# Split a string and get the first element in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I want an AppleScript that does the following:

- given a string (`Kdiff_full_call`) as a paramenter
- split a string and get
- the first element, which is a path to a zip file
- unzip the file in the `Downloads` directory

How can I do that in AppleScript?

`Kdiff_full_call` has the following pattern: string1-string2 string3 string4

So far I have this script:

```
on open location kdiff_full_call
    set array to my theSplit(kdiff_full_call, "-")
    -- set string1 ... ??
do shell script "/usr/bin/unzip -d " & quoted form of string1
end open location

on theSplit(theString, theDelimiter)
    -- save delimiters to restore old settings
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    -- set delimiters to delimiter to be used
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    -- create the array
    set theArray to every text item of theString
    -- restore the old setting
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    -- return the result
    return theArray
end theSplit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you were pretty close. in AS an array is a list of items. so you can access it like:

```
set string1 to array's item 1
-- or
set string1 to item 1 of array
```

or better if the pattern never changes and you always have the same amount of strings

```
set {string1,string2,string3,string4} to array
```

I'd recommend to rename your vars according to their content for better understanding. Instead of string1 I'd take filePath (or whatever)